# $routeProvider not loading template when url has a parameter

Tags: angularjs

I have successfully use angular's `$routeProvider` to load templates using code similar to this

```
$routeProvider.when('/store', {
    templateUrl: 'views/store.html',
    controller: 'StoreController'
});
```

However, when I use the code below nothing happens. That is, my template is not loaded. I think this must be because I have a parameter in the url, but I'm not exactly sure.

```
$routeProvider.when('/item/:item_id/info', {
    templateUrl: 'views/item.html',
    controller: 'ItemsCtrl'
});
```

How can I get this to work?

UPDATE:
To be clear, my links look like this: `ng-click="setRoute('/item/1/info')"` where "1" is the parameter.

UPDATE2:

```
$scope.setRoute = function(route){ $location.path(route); };
```

UPDATE3:

The parameter `:item_id` is being loaded via `$http`. When I inspect the source code for the page I see the parameter (e.g., "123"), but for some reason it is not bound to my `setRoute` function. If I hard code the parameter then everything works, but obviously I don't want to hard code it. How can I bind the url parameter so it works?

Comment: did you check the console are u getting some type of error

Comment: no errors are reported in the console.

Comment: did u try '/item/:item_id/:info'

Comment: Does `setRoute` update your location bar URL?

Comment: Need to see what "setRoute" does.

Comment: @aaronfrost Here is the function: ``$scope.setRoute = function(route){ $location.path(route); };``

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your partials absolute as in:

```
templateUrl: '/views/item.html',
```

When a parameter is added it looks at it as another depth of directory and wants to load something like `/item/views/item.html`